# Mysql error 10061 on local network

Tags: mysql, localhost

I'm tryig to connect to a local server his databases (located at 192.168.0.198),
but I'm getting the 10061 error.

When I try connecting true putty (then just an normal mysql login) it gives me no problems.
A mincraft plugin uses the following command to login to the database: `mysql://localhost:3306/DB_NAME` no problems there.

But when I try it with mysql workbench, and cmd. It refuses to work.

Anyone got any idea/solution how I could fix this?

grt kiwi

Comment: Have you gone through the steps at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html ("Make sure [...] that [the server] has not been configured to listen only locally on its network interfaces"; "Check to make sure that there is no firewall blocking access to MySQL"; etc.)?

Answer (score 8):

i had the exact same problem with the exact error message.

after reading @ruakh's comment i checked my.cnf and I noticed that the mysql server is bind to 127.0.0.1 ip address which is a loopback that can be reached only locally.

when i changed it to bind to the regular ip address (not loop) it resolved the issue. i could connect properly. you should try that ! :)

good luck

Comment: This answer saved my life... Check the bind_address parameter on the my.cnf file

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem. Changed the key type from ppk to pem and all worked fine.