# How to connect with my local ip in mysql server

Tags: database-connection, mysql-workbench, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have installed MySQL server 
my local ip is 172.16.1.110
I want to connect with this ip and have my own database
it enables me to connect with localhost only

when I connect with my ip
it gives me an error as image below

[image]

but I can connect from another ip with my ip in mysql

please help

Comment: try connecting to localhost or 127.0.0.1

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968406/mysql-error-10061-on-local-network

Comment: I saied it enables me to connect with localhost or 172.0.0.1 But, I want to connect with my ip

Comment: @Harry I see the problem in link you refer to But, I can't find the my.cnf in program files

Comment: have you tried programfiles(x86)@Nesreenadly

Comment: @Harry yes. but I can't find it also ... I really suck :(

Comment: have you tried localhost or 127.0.0.1?

Comment: @Harry yes................. it enables me but I want to connect with mine ip

Comment: You can try to install it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL has a privilege systemt that allows to specify from which host a user can connect from. If you insist on using the IP and not the localhost or loopback address then add a user that can connect from that address.

You can either do that via command line using [CREATE USER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html) or log in to MySQL Workbench as admin via localhost and add a new user in the admin section you get when you open a connection:

[image]